# Feature request ActiveCollab - live (filterable) project time logs

Tags: rest, feed, activecollab

Our agency uses ActiveCollab for project management and time tracking. It would be great if I could query live time data and pull it into a Google sheet.

My end goal is to have a projects overview sheet where I can see how much time is allocated each month and then what's been used.

Comment: Wouldn't you get better results taking this up with the vendor of that product? If there is a public API that you are trying to code to, you should reference that API in your question along with a [mcve]. Be sure to research things that results from a search with terms like "ActiveCollab query live time data" (and show this research here with an [edit]) so others don't have to do this legwork for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack overflow is not the right place to request new features for 3rd party products.